# How to make Mockery overload option work properly on Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, mockery

I am trying to use `overload` option of [Mockery](https://github.com/mockery/mockery) library on Laravel 5.

My current environment:

- Laravel 5
- Mockery 1.0
- PHPUnit 7.5

I wrote this test case:

```php
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Mockery;
use Tests\TestCase;

/**
 * @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */
class RenewSignatureTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testHandle()
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock('overload:App\FooClass');

        $mock->shouldReceive('callBar')
            ->times(2);
    }
}
```

According to [documentation](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/mocking_hard_dependencies.html), this test should fail, but does not matter what I do, the test never fails! It always result in:

```
Time: 304 ms, Memory: 19.53 MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

If I remove the `overload:` option, the test fails. So I assume that I'm not using the library's methods as expected.

The new test:

```php
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Mockery;
use Tests\TestCase;

/**
 * @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */
class RenewSignatureTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testHandle()
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock('App\FooClass');

        $mock->shouldReceive('callBar')
            ->times(2);
    }
}
```

The result:

```
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method callBar(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_0__App_FooClass should be called exactly 2 times but called 0 times.
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Does anyone know how to use this option properly?

Answer (score -1):

Reading the page, I think this is the error you are looking for:

> When Mockery overloads a class, because of how PHP works with files,
> that overloaded class file must not be included otherwise Mockery will
> throw a “class already exists” exception. This is where autoloading
> kicks in and makes our job a lot easier.

The error that you're looking for will be caused if you remove these 2 lines from your test, which are added to the code in the second code sample, and in the third sample on the manual page:

```
 * @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
```

This means your code wont take advantage of the psr4 autoloader or any autoloader that is in place, and will create a new autoloader for you, at the expense of speed, since it wont be using your dumped classmap and has to build it up from scratch.

If you take the two lines above out, you will get the expected error, as it will try to overload your class with a class of the same name. That class will already be autoloaded, so you get a fatal error.

So if you want to block calls to `callBar`, and return void, that is what your code will be doing, which is correct.

Removing `overload` will mean your mock is no longer effective, as you will have to pass it through a constructor to get it to work.

Update:

With your update, I can conclude that your code must be running the mocked `callBar` method twice (not the actual `callBar` method), with your mock of `fooBar` class using `overload`. When the mocked method gets called, nothing inside the real `callBar` method actually happens, it just registers that it was called. If you're expecting it once for example, write `shouldReceive(1)` and then fix the code that your test runs.

When you remove the `overload`, the global injection doesnt take place, so your mock never gets injected. However, your mock `callBar` method on the mock class is still expecting to be ran twice, so you get the error. You will need to remove the 2 mock code lines completely from your test.

Keep the @ statements in, as it will help prevent the psr4 error outlined above.

Comment: Ok. I dont know I understood correctly, but, my problem is the fact that I have exactly the same class in two situations: 1- if a put the overload option, the test passes (which should not happens, cause I explicitly says that fooBar needs to be called 2 times) 2- if I remove overload option, the test fails, saying that Mockery_0__App_FooClass should be called exactly two times. Why do this happens?

Comment: PS: I know that i was not so much explicit. I'm sorry about that. I updated the question.

Comment: PS2: "Why do this happens" means "Why do I not have same result in both classes?"

Comment: PS3: Remeber that I'm using Laravel's TestCase. Wich means that there are implicit methods, like setUp and tearDown implemented by the framework. If you want, I can post here those methods.

Comment: PS4: even if I remove those "@ comments" and run this test alone, I get same results.

Comment: Ive updated the question. take a look. You can try posting your code if you want, but I think you have the basis for actually diagnosing the issue with this test in place.

Answer (score -2):

This is not the way to test, you should never use `overload:` option... Laravel helps you with a lot of things, don't create the wheel again or try to...

Why would you need to use `@runTestsInSeparateProcesses` and `@preserveGlobalState disabled` ?

---

Let's say your test is like this:

```php
namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\FooClass;
use App\Service\ServiceForTesting;
use Mockery;
use Tests\TestCase;

class RenewSignatureTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testHandle()
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock(FooClass::class);

        $mock->shouldReceive('callBar')
            ->times(2);

        $myClass = app(ServiceForTesting::class);
        $myClass->run($mock);
        $myClass->run($mock);
    }
}
```

You should have a code like this:

```php
namespace App;

class FooClass
{
    public function callBar()
    {
        return 'Works !!!';
    }
}
```

Now, let's say you have a standalone class (no controller or similar, you are in a unit test), you should have something like this:

```php
namespace App\Service;

use App\FooClass;

class ServiceForTesting
{
    public function run(FooClass $class)
    {
        return $class->callBar();
    }
}
```